# Magento - Out Of Stock products showing

Tags: php, magento

I'm having an issue with Magento (CE 1.9.0.1) and out of stock products displaying on the category page. The configuration looks fine, I've flushed the cache and also the Indexes are up to date. There is a configurable which has 1 simple product assigned. The configurable product is set up to manage stock, and the simple product is also set up to manage stock, with a qty of 0 and Out of Stock. I have the same set up on another Magento site, when one of the simple products are set to 0 and Out of Stock, the Configurable product will then become out of stock and not display on the category.

System -> Configuration -> Inventory ([Screenshot](http://www.d3v.me.uk/ss/inventory-configuration.png))

- Manage Stock: Yes
- Backorders: No Backorders
- Qty for Items: 0

Configurable Product ([Screenshot](http://www.d3v.me.uk/ss/configurable.png))

- Manage Stock: Yes
- Stock Availability: In Stock

Simple Product ([Screenshot](http://www.d3v.me.uk/ss/simple.png))

- Everything has "Use Config Settings" checked
- Manage Stock: Yes
- Qty: 0
- Stock Availability: Out of Stock

Comment: Unless you've modified the code, (in which case please share your modifications) this question should probably be posted here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://colin.mollenhour.com/2009/06/02/hiding-out-of-stock-items-in-magento/) is the link to the tutorial which creates a simple module which hides the out of stock products from the product listing page.It also works for configurable products.So check it out.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a configuration setting at

`Admin >> System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Stock Options >> Display Out of Stock product`